# How to fill and merge df with 10 empty rows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

how to fill df with empty rows or create a df with empty rows.

have df :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["naming","type"])
```

how to fill this df with empty rows

Answer (score 1):

Specify index values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["naming","type"], index=range(10))
print (df)
  naming type
0    NaN  NaN
1    NaN  NaN
2    NaN  NaN
3    NaN  NaN
4    NaN  NaN
5    NaN  NaN
6    NaN  NaN
7    NaN  NaN
8    NaN  NaN
9    NaN  NaN
```

If need empty strings:

```
df = pd.DataFrame('',columns=["naming","type"], index=range(10))
print (df)
  naming type
0            
1            
2            
3            
4            
5            
6            
7            
8            
9
```

Comment: IMO,you can also mention that if requirement is adding 10 rows on the already created df, `df.reindex(range(10))`